# Why does express show "error can not set headers after they are sent" in this method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a nodejs app which uses express. When I try to call this method below I get logged in console "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

I found some other threads here about it being the async-methods, but I cant seem to pinpoint where its wrong in my code. I tried console logging, and the last place that logs before the return is just after this try catch. I also added "Return" before sending res.status to all my code, but it still emits this error. The code in the controller is much longer, but no console.logs where made after this piece of code. Any idas what Im doing wrong?

```
  router.post('/add', auth, async (req, res) => {

    if(req.body.mobilenumber === ''){
      return res.status(400).send('Bad input data, please check input.')
    }

    const checkUserText = 'SELECT * FROM SQL';
    let dbResult1;
            try {
                    dbResult1 = await GetStuff(checkUserText, [req.body.mobilenumber]);
            } catch (err) {
                    logger.error(err)
                    return res.status(500).send(err)
                }

                if (dbResult1.rowCount === null || dbResult1.rowCount >= 1) {
                 return res.sendStatus(405).send('User already exist')
            }

      var insertUser = 'INSERT INTO SQL RETURNING *';

      let dbResult2;
            try {
        let insData = [paramsFromBody];

        dbResult2= await GetStuff(insertUser, insData);
            } catch (err) {
                    logger.error(err)
                    return res.status(500).send(err)
      }

      if (dbResult2 === null || dbResult2.rowCount === 0) {
        return res.status(500).send('error')
        logger.error('Error')
      }
      return res.status(200).send('Added OK.')
  })

async function GetStuff(text, id){
    try {
        return await db.query(text, id);
      } catch(error) {
            throw new Error('Failed DB-action' + error);
      }
}
```

Comment: Is this really all of the code for this route handler?  It doesn't seem that this code all by itself would cause that error.  I'm guessing there's more code involved in this route handler somewhere or this isn't the route causing the problem.  For example, I notice that if `dbResult1.rowCount` is `1` or `0`, you don't send any response.  That doesn't seem right.  Code missing?  Also, `Validationstuff` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: We could help you a lot better if you were responsive to questions asked here.  Your question by itself is not clear.  We asked some questions.  The speed at moving forward is completely gated by when you respond.  In the future, I'd suggest checking back several times in the first 15-20 minutes after posting to see if your question was fully understood or not.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 ! Sorry for the late reply. This is not all code, I have 3 more DB-calls like the first that happens and gets evaluated through the post. But if i return res.status.send the controller should stop executing and end the call, right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It depends upon where you're doing the return from.  If you're doing the return from inside an async callback, then that doesn't return from the top level function or stop other code from running there.  We have to see ALL the code of this route to help you.  And, taking 6 days to respond is just not the way to use stack overflow.

Comment: I have updated the question with the whole code, sorry for the late reply!

Comment: So you have to nest If-statements and return from outside of the async callback like "dbResult2= await GetStuff(insertUser, insData);" when you want to do multiple hits on the DB?

Comment: Because you're using `async` and `await`, your return statements look OK to me except for the one mentioned below in  my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the code you've shared, this will cause the error you report:

```
return res.sendStatus(405).send('User already exist')
```

because `.sendStatus()` sends the whole response immediately and then `.send()` tries to send another response.  That should be this:

```
return res.status(405).send('User already exist');
```

---

Also, you can simplify `GetStuff()` to just this:

```
function GetStuff(text, id) {
    return db.query(text, id).catch(err => {
        throw new Error('Failed DB-action' + err);
    });
}
```

One clue is that there's pretty much never a reason to do:

```
return await fn();
```

You can just do:

```
return fn();
```

Both return the same promise with the same resolved value.

---

Also, note that in this code:

```
  if (dbResult2 === null || dbResult2.rowCount === 0) {
    return res.status(500).send('error')
    logger.error('Error')
  }
```

The `logger.error()` will never get called since it's after a `return` statement.

---

Your code could be simplified by using one central try/catch and only sending the response in two places (one for success and one for error):

```
// our own error subclass that holds a status value
class ResponseError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, status) {
        super(msg);
        this.status = status;
    }
}

router.post('/add', auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        if (req.body.mobilenumber === '') {
            throw new ResponseError('Bad input data, please check input.', 400);
        }

        const checkUserText = 'SELECT * FROM SQL';
        let dbResult1 = await GetStuff(checkUserText, [req.body.mobilenumber]);

        if (dbResult1.rowCount === null || dbResult1.rowCount >= 1) {
            throw new ResponseError('User already exist', 405);
        }

        const insertUser = 'INSERT INTO SQL RETURNING *';
        let dbResult2 = await GetStuff(insertUser, [paramsFromBody]);

        if (dbResult2 === null || dbResult2.rowCount === 0) {
            throw new ResponseError("dbResult2 empty", 500);
        }
        res.send('Added OK.')
    } catch(e) {
        // if no specific status specified, use 500
        let status = e.status || 500;
        res.status(status).send(e);
    }
})

function GetStuff(text, id) {
    return db.query(text, id).catch(err => {
        throw new Error('Failed DB-action' + error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very good explanation. My IDE (Vs code) was telling me that res.status was deprecated, so I think thats where they res.SendStatus came from. Seems to be working fine now! Also a big thanks for the code example. Im still new to Javascript and especially async so its a big help to see code like this. Thanks!